# Create queue of tasks that complete via delegate callbacks

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, queue, nsoperationqueue

My app allows people to share pieces of content they've created via Facebook, Twitter, Email, and SMS. Each of these options has a corresponding UISwitch. The user configures all the switches and then presses a "Done" button. For each switch,  if set to 'ON', I fire off an appropriate method (`shareViaSms`, `shareViaEmail`, etc.) which instantiates the native iOS viewControllers to accomplish that type of sharing (TWTweetComposeViewController, MFMailComposeViewController, etc.). These viewControllers have delegate callbacks to signal their completion, and when one completes (someone sends or cancels the email compose sheet), I need to fire off the next one they wanted to use.

My current code that manages this feels kludgy, and I'm seeking a better solution. If the user turns on all 4 options, I call the first share method `shareViaFacebook.` That has a delegate method, where upon completion, I check for the UISwitch status of the next share option, and if it's on, call it's share method, if not, check the next switch, and so on and so on. Each delegate's completion method loops through the remaining switches and is responsible for calling the next share method. As you could imagine, adding a new option requires changing a lot of code and modifying many if/else conditions.

How can I improve this? I would love to be able to simply look at all the UISwitches, and if set to "ON", add my corresponding share method (`shareViaSMS`) to some queue, and then have that queue run and have the next share method automatically called when the previous one completes. I'm struggling because, as mentioned earlier, the completion is asynchronous and is announced via a delegate callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a "manager" object for this which accepts a "request" object which will contain all the necessary information to start the specific request you want (name of service, text, title, etc.).

The "manager" object contains an array of tasks which you will load with requests objects, and it has to use recursivity by using the delegate and popping out the request as soon as its completed.

The delegate should call a method inside the manager which does something like:

If the request was completed successfully, pop the top of the stack and call again the manager's perform top of the stack request method.

If the request failed, stop and send a message.

If the stack is null all the requests have been performed.

Of course your manager has to have the approppiate code to handle each type of request.

If you have this architecture, adding a new service is as simple as just adding the code to manage that type of request to the manager object.

**By the way, this is one of many ways you can create a queue, I am suggesting this one because it is language independent and easy to understand in my opinion.**

Comment: This all pretty much makes sense. Two questions though. 1) when you say "the delegate should call a method inside the manager" are you referring to each delegate of the respective share option? Like MFMailComposeDelegate and MFMessageComposeDelegate? 2) How do I push a viewController, such as MFMailComposeViewController, onto the stack when all my logic will now be encapsulated in the manager object. I thought you could only push new viewController's from an existing viewController. Should my manager keep a reference to the viewController that instantiated it?

Comment: For your first question yes, each share option has its own callback, this callback should call the manager object so that the queue can continue. For your second question what you said seems to be the best solution, it really depends on the tasks you perform. If presenting new controllers is needed then the manager has to have a reference to the VC that will present it.